# Remember text in entry Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Hello I'm new to coding and I'm trying figure out the best way to remember the text in an entry in Xamarin Forms after the user closes and reopens the app. Any help on the best way to do this would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Forms has a build in [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#properties-dictionary) dictionary that can be used to store small bits of data persistently

```
// to save
Application.Current.Properties["myTextValue"] = myEntry.Value;

// to load
myEntry.Value = (string)Application.Current.Property["myTextValue"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite or Plugin.Setrings nugets. SQLite is better in the long run